# Displaying multer-uploaded images on template from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, multer

I'm working on a project using Node.js, Express, MongoDB, EJS, and Multer. I am new to Node, and this is my first time using multer, I've successfully been able to upload single images to my mongodb database using mongoose and multer, they appear in my destination file, `destination: './static/uploads'` as well as the db, as i checked using the mongodb shell, after doing the upload. Then after using a GET request to find all of the images, I'm stuck trying to display the image on a page after a GET request to find all photos and display using a for loop, I cannot seem to find much information on this part of the topic. I'd appreciate if someone can tell me where i'm going wrong based on my routes and views below, or provide me with a source of information on the topic.

Here is key parts my server.js file:

```
// Set Storage Engine and Changing filename
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './static/uploads',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

// Init Upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
}).single('file');

// Validate Image Type
function checkFileType(file, cb) {
   const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
   const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

    if (mimetype && extname) {
        return cb(null, true);
    } else {
       cb(new Error("Images only!"));
    }

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './static')));
}
```

And here are the routes in question. Also in my server.js.

```
//Post route to upload image and add to database
app.post('/new-image', (req, res) => {
    if (req.file && req.body) {
        let msg = "Fields Required";
        console.log("Fields were null");
        res.render("admin.ejs", { msg: msg });
    } else {
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", err);
                res.render('admin.ejs', { msg: err });
            } else {
                var image_inst = new Image({ 
                    title: req.body.title, 
                    filename: req.file.path, 
                    briefDesc: req.body.breifdesc, 
                    description: req.body.desc 
                });
                console.log("image inst: ", image_inst)
                image_inst.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('something went wrong', err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('successfully added a Image!');
                        res.redirect('/admin');
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
});

//GET Route to display on index page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Image.find({}, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("something went wrong", err);
        } else {
            var image = { image: data };
            console.log(image);
            console.log(data);
        }

        res.render('index.ejs', { image: image });
    })
});
```

Here what is console.log() from the GET Route:

```
{ image:
[ { _id: 5c897086af2ef22e4cfc77e7,
   title: 'test',
   filename: 'static\\uploads\\file-1552511110186.jpg',
   briefDesc: 'test',
   description: 'test',
   __v: 0 } ] }
[ { _id: 5c897086af2ef22e4cfc77e7,
    title: 'test',
    filename: 'static\\uploads\\file-1552511110186.jpg',
    briefDesc: 'test',
    description: 'test',
__v: 0 } ]
```

I'm not sure why the filename has two "\" between directories, I think that could be a source of the problem but i'm not sure why that's happening.

And here is the portion the index.ejs where I am trying to display the image.

```
<% for (var i in images) { %>
<figure class="effect-portfolio wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="2s">
    <img src="<%= images[i].filename %>" alt="02_img" /> <!-- image -->
    <figcaption>
        <!-- Caption -->
        <h2><%= images[i].title %></h2>
        <p><%= images[i].description %></p>
        <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">View more</a>

    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I believe this is all the relevant information, i'd be happy to answer any questions or provide more information. Thanks so much!